# When is set and get method called in apex class and whats the issue when we don't use it?

Tags: apex, visualforce, method

```
public class opportunityextension2{
    public List<opportunity> opplist{get; set;}

    public opportunityextension2(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {

    }

    public opportunityextension2(){
        opplist = [select name, id from opportunity];
    }

    public pagereference  exportbutton(){
        return page.Exportbuttonpage; 
    }

}
```

Can someone please tell me when the get and set method is called?
in the above code, if the set and get method is not provided then

```
 public opportunityextension2(){
     opplist = [select name, id from opportunity];
 }
```

won't above code set opplist with name and id from opportunity. what if we don't use set and get what is the problem we get.
if anyone can clear me it is really appreciated.
Thanks

VF page

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity"  recordSetVar="Opportunities" extensions="opportunityextension2" >
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock >

        <apex:pageblockSection >

        <apex:commandButton value="Export to excel" action="{!exportbutton}" /> <br/>
            <apex:pageblocktable value="{!opportunities}" var="opp" rows="19">


                <apex:column value="{!opp.Name}"/>
                apex:column value="{!opp.ID}"/>

            </apex:pageblocktable>


        </apex:pageblockSection>
         <apex:commandButton value="First" action="{!First}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!Next}" disabled="{!NOT(hasnext)}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!previous}" disabled="{!NOT(hasprevious)}" />
         <apex:commandButton value="Last" action="{!Last}" />

    </apex:pageblock>



 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The get and set method are methods contained in an **Apex Property** https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm.

The *get* method is called anytime that the property is **read**, and the *set* property is called anytime that the property is set. If you don't define either, they are considered Automatic Properties, where the get method returns the value and the set method sets the value.

Some interesting and useful features of an Apex Property (which can be read in the link above), is that you can define a value as only *readable* or only *writeable* by only specifying the get method for readable, or the set method for writeable.

Your code could therefore be rewritten like the following:

```
Public class opportunityextension2{

    public list<opportunity> opplist{
        get {
            return [select name, id from opportunity];
        }, set;
    }

    public opportunityextension2(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {

    }

    public pagereference  exportbutton(){
        return page.Exportbuttonpage; 
    }
}
```

This means that anytime the opplist property is accessed (or *read*), it will execute the query and return the results. Maybe this isn't the most efficient implementation, but it demonstrates the purpose of an Apex Property.

Comment: i guess the thing that i dont understand is when is the get and set method called, i dont see the methods getting called ? i am sorry i started programming here, i used to do java alittle before where i have used this methods but i remember calling it explicitly but i dont see it being called here,please clear me on that. also thanks for the links.

Comment: No problem, it is a kind of confusing concept, and not really used in Java. In your original code, when you call the method opportunityextension2(), you are then explicitly setting the property opplist. This means that at this moment, the set method is executed in the property. The get method would be executed when you reference the property from the Visualforce Page of the controller, for example.

Comment: i have added the VF page, if you may please explain when is get method called. get method name has to be used in VF page to call the method right?

Comment: In the VF page, whenever you access the property through a reference, say {!oppList}, the the get method will be executed. In your page, you are never referencing the property, so the get method is never executed.

Comment: I get it now, i am referencing that in an another vf page ,that vf page is for the export button in defined in the controller class, Thanks

Comment: Yeah no problem. Up-vote my answer if you think it's helpful. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

In order for Visualforce to interact with Apex Code data, it *requires* getters and setters. This is a Visualforce limitation, not an Apex Code limitation. By default, Apex Code gets read and write permission to a variable if no permissions are set, while Visualforce gets **no** permission to a variable if no permissions are set (this results in a compilation error in Visualforce). In other words, without a getter/setter, Apex Code can run the query and assign the results to the variable, but Visualforce won't be able to read the results from the controller's variable.

Answer (score 1):

If declared get and set properties for field, then when setting values for field calls setter.

```
public Integer i {
    set {
        i = value;
        System.debug(i);
    }
}
```

doing assignment `i = 4;` will result to writing debug.

> DEBUG|4

When getting value of field getter is called

```
public Integer i {
    get {
        i = 4;
        System.debug(i);
        return i;
    }
}
```

In this case, `Integer b = i;` will result to assign 4 to b variable and debug will be displayed

if set or get property is not provided, then it is normally to access field with any access modifier from the same class, so values for `opplist` would be set in your example.  It is not a good practice to make field `public` without getters and setters.

to learn more about apex properties read [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm)

Comment: i guess the thing that i don't understand is when is the get and set method called, i don't see the methods getting called ? i am sorry i started programming here, i used to do java a little before where i have used this methods but i remember calling it explicitly but i don't see it being called here,please clear me on that. thanks